# what is the best way to start google chrome and input a web address by pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

I learn from blog (http://technapstar.blogspot.fi/2014/07/automation-with-pywinauto.html) about starting google chrome and input a web address by pywinauto as the following way:

```
Python 3.6.1rc1 (v3.6.1rc1^0:e0fbe5feee4f9c00f09eb9659c2182183036261a, Mar  4 2017, 20:00:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import pywinauto
>>> pywinauto.__version__
'0.6.2'
>>> from pywinauto.application import Application
>>> app = Application().start("chrome.exe")

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 982
    UserWarning)
UserWarning: 32-bit application should be automated using 32-bit Python (you     use 64-bit Python)
>>> app.window_(title='New Tab')
<pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification object at 0x0000000002FFABE0>
>>> app.window_().TypeKeys('{F6}')
<pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.DialogWrapper object at 0x0000000004258320>
>>> app.window_().TypeKeys('{ESC}')
<pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.DialogWrapper object at 0x0000000004243518>
>>> app.window_().TypeKeys('www.google.com')
<pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.DialogWrapper object at 0x0000000004225D68>
>>> app.window_().TypeKeys('{ENTER}')
<pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.DialogWrapper object at 0x00000000042436D8>
>>>
```

However, when I try to start another google chrome window with the same way, I meet the following error.

```
>>> app1 = Application().start("chrome.exe")

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 982
    UserWarning)
UserWarning: 32-bit application should be automated using 32-bit Python (you use 64-bit Python)
>>> app1.window_(title='New Tab')
<pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification object at 0x0000000004243470>
>>> app1.window_().TypeKeys('{F6}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 243, in __resolve_control
    criteria)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 424, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    app1.window_().TypeKeys('{F6}')
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 365, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 246, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 402, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 188, in __get_ctrl
    dialog = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**criteria[0]))
```

I google a bit, but could not find the answers. Can somebody suggest what is the best way to operate google chrome by pywinauto? or pywinauto is not a proper tool to operate google chrome at the moment.

[EDIT]
Still not working by following Vasily's student sample code, see here:

```
>>> app = Application(backend='uia');
>>> app.start('chrome.exe --force-renderer-accessibility')
<pywinauto.application.Application object at 0x00000000045D80B8>
>>> app.window().type_keys('{F6}')
<pywinauto.controls.uiawrapper.UIAWrapper object at 0x00000000045D8AC8>
```

So far it is ok, but when I try to have another chrome browser, I meet following error:

```
>>> app1 = Application(backend='uia');
>>> app1.start('chrome.exe --force-renderer-accessibility')
<pywinauto.application.Application object at 0x0000000003324F28>
>>> app1.window().type_keys('{F6}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 243, in __resolve_control
    criteria)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 424, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    app1.window().type_keys('{F6}')
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 365, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 246, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 402, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 188, in __get_ctrl
    dialog = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**criteria[0]))
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'backend': 'uia', 'process': 2832}
>>>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to run Chrome with accessibility features enabled for all pages (here are some [tips and tricks on that](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/How-to-enable-accessibility-(tips-and-tricks))):

```
app = Application().start('chrome.exe --force-renderer-accessibility')
```

Second Chrome could be easier automated using `backend='uia'` (MS UI Automation technology) and you need to specify it explicitly. More details about backends and pywinauto fundamentals could be found in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) (really recommend to read for everyone). It also explains where to find Inspect.exe to browse UI elements hierarchy and much-much more. Just a small example:

```
app = Application(backend='uia').start('chrome.exe --force-renderer-accessibility')
```

Third Chrome may start new tabs in different process. So you need to connect to this new process using `title` or `title_re` criterion.

```
app_new_tab = Application(backend='uia').connect(path='chrome.exe', title_re='New Tab')
```

Alternative way is to use `Desktop` object (process agnostic way):

```
NewTab = Desktop(backend='uia').NewTab
NewTab.print_control_identifiers() # prints UI elements subtree
```

[EDIT] My student wrote an example script dragging zip file from explorer.exe to Google Drive using Chrome in incognito mode: [test_explorer_google_drive.py](https://github.com/vasily-v-ryabov/ui-automation-course/blob/master/02_google_drive_Murashov/test_explorer_google_drive.py). Tested on English version.

```
# encoding: utf-8
from __future__ import print_function
from os import path
from pywinauto import Desktop, Application

chrome_dir = r'"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"'
tab_log_in = u'Meet Google Drive - One place for all your files (Incognito)'
tab_drive = 'My Drive - Google Drive (Incognito)'

# # start google chrome
chrome = Application(backend='uia')
chrome.start(chrome_dir + ' --force-renderer-accessibility --incognito --start-maximized '
             'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https:'
             '//drive.google.com/?urp%3Dhttps://www.google.ru/_/chrome/newtab?espv%253D2%2526ie%253DUT%23&followup='
             'https://drive.google.com/?urp%3Dhttps://www.google.ru/_/chrome/newtab?espv%253D2%2526ie%253DUT'
             '&ltmpl=drive&emr=1#identifier')

# wait while a page is loading
chrome[tab_log_in].child_window(title_re='Reload.*', control_type='Button').wait('visible', timeout=10)
ch_window = chrome[tab_drive].child_window(title="Google Chrome", control_type="Custom")

# log in
chrome.window().type_keys('TestPywinauto{ENTER}')  # username
chrome[tab_log_in].child_window(title="Google Chrome", control_type="Custom").\
    child_window(title="Back", control_type="Image").wait(wait_for='visible', timeout=10)

chrome.window().type_keys('testpywinauto123{ENTER}')  # password
ch_window.child_window(title="Getting started PDF", control_type="ListItem").wait(wait_for='visible')

# start explorer in the current path
dir_path = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), 'UIA_Drive')
explorer = Application().start('explorer.exe ' + dir_path)
Desktop(backend='uia').window(title='UIA_Drive', active_only=True).wait('visible', timeout=10)
dlg = Application(backend='uia').connect(path='explorer.exe', title='UIA_Drive')

# find file
file = dlg.UIA_Drive.ItemsView.wrapper_object().get_item('test.zip')

# drag n drop
destination = chrome.top_window().wrapper_object()
file.press_mouse_input(coords=file.rectangle().mid_point())
file.move_mouse_input(coords=destination.rectangle().mid_point())
chrome.top_window().set_focus()
file.release_mouse_input(coords=destination.rectangle().mid_point())

# wait upload file
ch_window.child_window(title="test.zip Compressed Archive", control_type="ListItem").wait('visible')

print('DONE')
```

Comment: Hi Vasily, Thanks a lot for the answer. May I ask for a simple example to type URL in chrome by pywinauto? As I tried, but could not succeed.

Comment: Hi Vasily, I try to follow your student example, and write very simple program. The first time open chrome and type a key is ok, but the second time fails. I have edit my question with the errors, very simple code, could you please have a look and tell what is wrong?

Comment: I see you already figured it out (since the answer is accepted). If you need more help, feel free to ask more questions here or on GitHub.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov can we make the same chrome window to run with a proxy server by specifying something like this :

Comment: chrome.start(chrome_dir + ' --force-renderer-accessibility --proxy-server=https://8f1a9ff2e5:pukbL2Vd@23.229.62.213:4444 --incognito --start-maximized '
                              'https://whatismyipaddress.com/')

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Can You please help me on this? I want to run chrome with proxy, please see my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60027951/run-google-chrome-with-proxy-using-pywinauto

Comment: Sorry, I'm too overloaded. Need to focus on new features.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler way to start is this :

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
chrome_dir = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
start_args = ' --force-renderer-accessibility --start-maximized https://www.google.com/'
app = Application(backend="uia").start(chrome_dir+start_args)
```